# Clean up Drug Display Term records (Health Cloud)

Tags: health-cloud, data-storage

Drug Display Term records consume ~25Mb of storage, which is significant in sandboxes with 200Mb storage capacity.
[image: storage usage]

On all records, the last modified by field has autoproc value. I have the feeling that these records were generated by Health Cloud automatically.

The records are only available from Classic if the user has a “Health Cloud Platform” license.

I am not sure if they can be deleted, despite having the delete permission on the profile - the standard Salesforce UI does not allow this.

It's not even possible to execute a SOQL query:

```
SELECT Id FROM DrugDisplayTerm

// org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: INVALID_TYPE: sObject type 'DrugDisplayTerm' is not supported.
```

Does anyone know how to clean them up?